# Not working, Javascript validating text input before button click

Tags: javascript, html

The code is suppose to validate an input and then execute a function when a button is clicked, but it is not working and the console does not suggest why. The only difference is that when you take away toString() on input it says it is not a function.
This is my first big project at university and not really sure which part is wrong?

```
function check(evt){
    const value = input.value;

    if (!value) {
      input.dataset.state = ''
      return
    }

    const trimmed = input.toString().trim();

    if (trimmed) {
      input.dataset.state = 'valid'
    } else {
      input.dataset.state = 'invalid'
    }
  }
```

Function to be executed

```
function addRow() {
something...
}
```

validating if this function is true then execute this function.

```
function validate(){
         if(check()){
            addRow();
            }
}
```

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', check);
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', validate);
```

Html

```
 <input type="text" id="input" class="input" autofocus autocomplete="off" placeholder="Add items in your list..">
 <button id='btn' class="add">+</button>
```

Comment: At `input.toString().trim();`, what value is `input`? And what are you trying to do there?

Comment: Input should be a string without spaces

Comment: Trim will only strip value from the start and on the end: " test  test  "=> "test  test"

Comment: Yes that is what I need, it can be string with space in the middle

Answer (score 1):

Although the `input` variable is not declared in your code, I assume that it is supposed to represent the `<input type="text">` element.

With the validation step you should validate the `value` of the input, not the input itself.

But your logic is still missing something. The `else` statement will never be reached. If the `value` is empty then the state will be set to `''` and the function is stopped. If there is a value, and it has been trimmed, then you're always left with a string with a value in it and there for your value is *truthy*. So the `else` would not make without an `if` statement which would allow the value to be `false` when the validation is incorrect.

```
function check(evt){
  const value = input.value;

  if (!value) {
    input.dataset.state = ''
    return
  }

  // Trim the value.
  const trimmed = value.trim();

  if (trimmed) {
    input.dataset.state = 'valid'
  } else {
    input.dataset.state = 'invalid'
  }
}
```

Comment: Had to scrap it and use Jquery function for the button, thanks for the effort though